# Kubernetes pod custom monitoring

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, victoriametrics

I'm trying to implement python script which collect and parsing kubernetes pod manifest's image version and secretName of each pod in 2 various kubernetes clusters and then if there are any differences between 2 clusters - should be send an alert. These metrics for 2 clusters then should be parsed by instance of Victoria Metrics.
The problem is observed in if i check `kubectl describe pod_name` - in its output exists field secretName:

```
Volumes:
  cacert:
    Type:           Glusterfs (a Glusterfs mount on the host that shares a pod's lifetime)
    EndpointsName:  glusterfs-cluster
    Path:           test/jvm/cert
    ReadOnly:       false
  service-conf-secrets:
    Type:                Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    SecretName:          example-app-1.25.01-57409t3
    SecretOptionalName:  <nil>
```

But if I use `kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api` and its function `list_pod_for_all_namespaces` - can't find in its output secretName at all.

Where can I find and parse this field and make prometheus format metrics from these fields?

Comment: Please include a redacted example of a `kubectl describe {pod}` that includes a `secretName`. I'm unsure what property it is that you want. `kubectl describe` combines two underlying API calls. It `api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{pod}` and it `'api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/events?fieldSelector=`. You verify this for yourself with e.g. `kubectl describe pod/{name} -v=6`. `list_pod_for_all_namespaces` is only making the first API call (for each Pod).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The information you want should be available under `spec.volumes` for each item (`i`) returned by `v1.list_pod_for_all_namespace`. In your case, you'll get 2 items `[0]` (`cacert`) and `[1]` (`service-conf-secrets`). You can then convert the result into a dictionary e.g. `i.spec.volumes[1].projected.to_dict()` and you should be able to extract the `SecretName`

Comment: @DazWilkin I got error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_dict'.


`for i in api_instance.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False).items:
    print(i.spec.volumes[1].projected.to_dict())`

Output hasn't spec.volumes.

Comment: Not every `volume` has `protected`. Check for that before attempting `to_dict`

Comment: I don't have time today to write you an example but, can write something tomorrow?

Comment: @DazWilkin Ok, of course

Comment: Found some time this evening. I've added an "Answer" that enumerates Pod Volumes and prints `secret.name`'s and `path`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

I've includes comment references to the Python SDK's implementation of the Kubernetes types as well as the type hints for these types to help explain the use of the properties.

I've included the full enumeration of [`V1VolumeProjection`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1VolumeProjection.md) names including `secret` ([`V1SecretProjection`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1SecretProjection.md)) for completeness.

```py
from kubernetes import client,config

config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

# https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodList.md
pod_list: client.V1PodList = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
# Iterator over returned items (if any)
pods: list[client.V1Pod] = pod_list.items
for pod in pods:
    metadata: client.V1ObjectMeta = pod.metadata
    # https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1PodSpec.md
    spec: client.V1PodSpec = pod.spec
    print(f"{metadata.namespace}/{metadata.name} [{pod.status.pod_ip}]")
    # if pod.metadata.namespace=="shell-operator" and pod.metadata.name=="pods":
    # Iterative over volume (f any)
    # https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1Volume.md
    volumes: list[client.V1Volume] = spec.volumes
    for volume in volumes:
        if volume.projected:
            projected: client.V1ProjectedVolumeSource = volume.projected
            # https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1VolumeProjection.md
            sources: list[client.V1VolumeProjection] = projected.sources
            for source in sources:
                # if source.config_map:
                # if source.downward_api:
                if source.secret:
                    # https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1SecretProjection.md
                    secret: client.V1SecretProjection = source.secret
                    print(secret.name)
                    items: list[client.V1KeyToPath] = secret.items
                    for i in items:
                        path: str = i.path
                        print(path)
                # if source.service_account_token:
```